# Select highest value based off of a different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the highest value based off of another column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    AppDetailVehicleValuation.AppID, 
    VehicleValuationOption.Description, 
    MAX (VehicleValuationOptionValueType.Value)
FROM            
    AppDetailVehicleValuation
    INNER JOIN VehicleValuationOption 
        ON AppDetailVehicleValuation.ValuationID = VehicleValuationOption.ValuationID 
    INNER JOIN VehicleValuationOptionValueType 
        ON VehicleValuationOption.ValuationOptionID = VehicleValuationOptionValueType.ValuationOptionID
WHERE        
    (VehicleValuationOption.IsSelected LIKE '1') 
    AND (VehicleValuationOption.IsSystemOption LIKE '1')
```

What I have is this

```
AppID | Description | Value
999     Beats Audio   425.00
999     Beats Audio   475.00
999     Power Str.    600.00
999     Power Str.    750.00
```

this is what I need

```
AppID | Description | Value
999     Beats Audio   475.00
999     Power Str.  | 750.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
 SELECT
       t.AppId, 
       t.Description, 
       max(t.Value)
 FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.description, t.AppId
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely very helpful. You should explain why this works. Also, this will not quite work because it would also need to be grouped by t.AppId.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a GROUP BY clause in your query:

```
SELECT
    AppDetailVehicleValuation.AppID, 
    VehicleValuationOption.Description, 
    MAX (VehicleValuationOptionValueType.Value)
FROM            
    AppDetailVehicleValuation
    INNER JOIN VehicleValuationOption 
        ON AppDetailVehicleValuation.ValuationID = VehicleValuationOption.ValuationID 
    INNER JOIN VehicleValuationOptionValueType 
        ON VehicleValuationOption.ValuationOptionID = VehicleValuationOptionValueType.ValuationOptionID
WHERE        
    (VehicleValuationOption.IsSelected LIKE '1') 
    AND (VehicleValuationOption.IsSystemOption LIKE '1')
GROUP BY AppDetailVehicleValuation.AppID, VehicleValuationOption.Description
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Glad you found an answer that works with the GROUP BY. I would suggest you start using aliases in your queries. It can quickly and easily turn a wall of text into something fairly easy to see what is going on. You might end with something along these lines.

```
SELECT advv.AppID
    , vvo.Description
    , MaxValue = MAX(vvot.Value)
FROM AppDetailVehicleValuation advv
INNER JOIN VehicleValuationOption vvo ON advv.ValuationID = vvo.ValuationID 
INNER JOIN VehicleValuationOptionValueType vvot ON vvo.ValuationOptionID = vvot.ValuationOptionID
WHERE vvo.IsSelected = '1'
    AND vvo.IsSystemOption = '1'
group by advv.AppID
    , vvo.Description
```